# $ ssh -T git@github - permission denied (public key)

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I'm first time GitHub user. I installed Git for Windows, following instructions: http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/

Came to the point of generating a public ssh-key. Opened Git Bash. Generated the key, saved it on github.com in my SSH Public Keys, now trying ssh access:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What's wrong? The instruction sais that everything should go fine. Maybe I need to reboot or wait when github.com server gets to know my key?

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to [set up your *ssh keys*](http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/#_set_up_ssh_keys) and then [add your public key to your github account](https://github.com/account/ssh)

Comment: Thanks, c00kiemon5ter!

I'm on Windows XP, not Linux... that's the first note, and the second - I set up my ssh key, means that I generated the key file. Do I need to do something else on my client machine?..

Comment: setting up your _ssh keys_, means generating two files, one public (`id_rsa.pub` usually) and one private (`id_rsa`). Once you do that you need to add the `id_rsa.pub` to your github account (see the link I provided above). Once that's done you should be able to `ssh` and _authenticate_ to github. Try this:
`ssh -T git@github.com -i <path-to-id_rsa>`

Comment: This cure worked! Need to specify the path to the private key.

Answer (score 4):

```
    ssh-keygen -t rsa
    copy the key generated in the file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (open with notepad)
    paste this key in the "add ssh key" section of your github account
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Although every instruction was followed; Public Key genereated and added to my Github account, i kept getting the error...Until i restarted my machine.
I suggest you do the same. Hopefully this should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Had to use `exec ssh-agent bash`. It helped:

```
$ exec ssh-agent bash
bash-3.1$ ssh-add f:/GIT/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for f:/GIT/.ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: f:/GIT/.ssh/id_rsa (f:/GIT/.ssh/id_rsa)
bash-3.1$ ssh git@github.com
Hi MichaelZelensky! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provi
de shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

Answer (score 2):

For me (windows xp, reasonably fresh install) when generating the ssh keys via mingw32, the .ssh directory did not exist that I was saving the keys to.

Instead of ssh-keygen creating it, they were put in the root of the user directory (C:\Documents and Settings\).

This gave the Permission Denied (public key) error.

Simple solution...

Move the key files to the .ssh directory! (incidentally, this seemed to be created when I said yes to continue connecting after the authenticity of host.... message)

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate your ssh key

first get to the ssh directory

> cd ~/.ssh

Now generate a ssh key

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "YOUREMAILID"

Key will be generated. Now install x-clip using this command

> sudo apt install xclip

Now run the following command to copy the key to clipboard

> xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

replace id_rsa with the file location which you gave to save the key during generation
now run the following command to know whether it is properly executed

> ssh -T git@github.com

following message will occur

> Hi USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

now you are ready to perform any task in git without this issue...

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, I generated my ssh-keygen, after I added my public key to GitHub, and they told me same problem, but what happens you need give permission to folder .ssh, I solve that problem, I know is basic make that, but I was foregetting that, but check it, maybe is the same solution.

```
sudo chmod 777 -R .ssh
```

Comment: For those of you reading through this question, this is commonly regarded as a bad idea because 777 is extremely permissive, and considered a bad idea for just about everything.